# Keeping values in the same position in Masked input

Tags: jquery, html, maskedinput

I have a masked input text box which will take id and amount. But if the user enter only amount and come out of the text box the value is getting changed. Below is the code and example.

```
<label>Phone Number</label>
<input id="phone" type="text" value="" />
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#phone").mask("?a-9999 $99999.99");
});
```

The out put of the masking will be `A-1234 $12345.00`
if the user enter the amount like `A-1___ $12345.67` and comes out, the value became `A-1123 $4567_.67`. We want the value to saty as the user entered. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

[JSF Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vebyLdLx/1/)

Comment: @ketan I have added the Fiddle in my question pls check that. In your fiddle there jquery.maskedinput.js not added in external js option

Answer (score 0):

There are many masked input plugins for jQuery, and I didn't got which one you are using from the question.

I would suggest to just pick a better one here: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/mask/

You may want to use this one http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/

I built a jsfiddle here for implementing the same function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#phone").inputmask("a|A-9999 $99999.99");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/twksos/nvsvux7u/2/

Comment: We are using `jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.js`.